# How do create couchdb design docs with Nano in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Looking through the README it doesn't look there is a way to create design docs with Nano?  What are others doing for this?

Comment: Nano as in the terminal based editor?

Comment: "Nano" as in the couchdb client for Node.js: https://github.com/dscape/nano

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply use the `db.insert` function.

```
db.insert(design_doc, '_design/design_doc_name', callback);
```

Here's a more complete example (from [tests/view/query](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/4276f69f676669ccd9c77deecb77388cd93c092f/tests/design/query.js#L16-21)):

```
  db.insert(
  { "views": 
    { "by_name_and_city": 
      { "map": function(doc) { emit([doc.name, doc.city], doc._id); } } 
    }
  }, '_design/people', function (error, response) {
    console.log("yay");
  });
```

If you are interested in learning some more check this [sample](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/samples/lazy_creation_of_views.js) or go on and read the [CouchDB Guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/)

Comment: How about creating a new view? I assume, just get a design doc, add a view to it, and insert the design doc back in?